justifying time average of self-regulating dynamical system
I'm interested in the following dynamical system over $(x, y)$:
\begin{align*}
x'(t) &= x(t) \, y(t) \\
y'(t) &= \alpha(t) - x(t)
\end{align*}
where $\alpha(t)$ is an incoming signal.
Observe that $x$ grows exponentially whenever $y > 0$ and shrinks exponentially whenever $y < 0$.  Meanwhile, when $x$ is small, we have $y'(t) \approx \alpha(t)$, but when $x$ is large, $y$ gets pushed downwards.
Empirically, the net effect of these dynamics is to keep $y$ regulated below zero.  This is because whenever $y$ rises above zero, $x$ blows up exponentially, which in turn forces $y$ back below zero.
The blue lines in the subsequent figure plot these dynamics for three choices of $\alpha(t)$.

I am trying to analyze the "time averaged" dynamics of this system.   I have a feeling that the "right" answer is that the time-averaged variables $(\bar{x}, \bar{y})$ can be characterized as:
\begin{align*}
 \bar{x}(t) &= \begin{cases} 0 \quad &\mbox{if} \quad \bar{y}(t) <0 \\ \max(\alpha(t), 0) &\mbox{if} \quad \bar{y}(t) = 0 \end{cases} \\ \bar{y}'(t) &= \alpha(t) - \bar{x}(t)
\end{align*}
These dynamics are plotted in orange above; the dashed blue lines empirically measure the time averages (over the course of each cycle), verifying that the prediction is correct.  Intuitively, when $\bar{y} < 0$, this system models $x$ as decaying so fast that it can be treated as zero: $\bar{x} = 0$.  Meanwhile, when $\bar{y} = 0$, then so long as $\alpha > 0$, the system models $\bar{x}$ as the precise value that will keep $\bar{y}$ fixed at zero.  Once $\alpha$ turns negative, $\bar{x}$ becomes zero again and $\bar{y}$ drops below zero.
Is there a way to justify this more formally?

One piece of partial work is that for constant $\alpha$, the critical point at $(\alpha,0)$ changes from a center to a saddle point as $\alpha$ becomes negative. Perhaps a Lyapunov function or something similar could be used to prove the existence of the periodic orbit for $\alpha>0$ then the bifurcation to a saddle point as $\alpha$ becomes negative explains this behavior

The system is also equivalent to $u'' + e^u = \alpha(t)$, where $x = e^u$. This may be easier to work with for solutions where $x$ is bounded away from $0$.

More partial progress, periodic orbits exist for fixed $\alpha>0$ given by the level sets of $\frac{1}{2}y^2 + x - \alpha \ln x = C$, which is a conserved quantity for $x>0$, which is an invariant set.

Do you have any prior knowledge of the initial conditions and the input? for example, $x(0)>0$ or $\alpha(t) \in [\alpha_{min},\alpha_{max}]$ for all $t$?
